# How to express the future perfect progressive tense?

Tags: grammar, tense

Here's an example sentence in English with this tense

> On July 1st, it will have rained for 2 months

I understand that there's no such tense in Japanese, but how do I go about expressing it?
Here are some of my attempts

> ７月１日まで２ヶ月間で降ってくる

> ７月１日で２ヶ月間降ってくる

> ７月１日になると２ヶ月間降ってきた

Please let me know of the correct way of expressing this tense and if any of my examples made sense at all

Comment: Just to confirm intent -- it sounds like you're trying to express the future completion of an ongoing action.  Is that correct?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi not necessarily its completion. It may still be ongoing at this certain point in the future

Comment: I think the title is misleading. The future perfect *progressive* would be “it will have been raining”, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your examples makes sense. 降ってきた would be understood as meaning it has begun to rain. 降ってくる sounds like something will come down.

I would say:

> ７月１日で２ヶ月間降った (or 降り続けた) ことになる。

---

If you need to add the *progressive* aspect, the following would do:

> ７月１日で２ヶ月間降っている (or 降り続けている) ことになる。